# Specify path for image directory as a shared resource directory

Tags: wicket, jelastic

Currently I am specifying the path to a shared image directory in the wicket application as follows:

```
getSharedResources().add("images", new FolderContentResource(new File(this.getServletContext().getResource("/images").getFile())));
```

Following path does not work either:

```
getSharedResources().add("images", new FolderContentResource(new File("/opt/tomcat/webapps/test/images")));
```

When deploying the application to Jelastic/Tomcat, the images cannot be retrieved. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to Jelastic's documentation (http://docs.jelastic.com/environment-variables) `user.home   /opt/tomcat/temp` is your user space. You should put your stuff there.
Check this article http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/ for inspiration how to do it.

Notes:
 - Jelastic's docu says "environment variables" but "user.home" looks like a system property to me
- the folder name is `temp`, so it may get cleaned by Jelastic in some conditions. Read their documentation to be sure when this may occur.

Comment: Despite the name `temp` does not get cleaned by Jelastic